# Function that takes an generic array of values that can be undefined and return a boolean marking them defined - example in question

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I struggled writing the title so here an example with code explaining what my goal is.

So I can write a function like this

```
function isDefined<T>(value: T | undefined): value is T {
  return value !== undefined;
}
```

is there a way to type a function that does this for an array of values? Like for example if I had something like:

```
const name: string | undefined = getName();
const birthdate: LocalDate | undefined = getBirthDate();
const car: Car | undefined = getCar();

if (allValuesAreDefined(name, birthdate, car) {
  // here I want TS to know that all these variables are indeed not undefined
}

// ? marks the spot I don't know how to type
function allValuesAreDefined<?>(...values: (? | undefined)[]): values is ?[] {
  return values.every(value => value !== undefined);
}
```

Obviously my example is very simple and can be easily be implemented without the use of such function but I'm very curious if creating something allValuesAreDefined is generally possible.

my goal would be to use it after an if statement and the not being able to check if each individual value is undefined, like so:

```
if (allValuesAreDefined(name, birthdate, car) {
  console.log(name.concat(' you suck, no sorry, actually I do');
  console.log(car.manufacturer.name)
  console.log(LocalDate.now().minusYears(18).isBefore(age) ? 'Sorry dude your are underage' : 'Welcome to...')
}
```

Thanks to all of you taking the time!

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Why not `isDefined(name) && isDefined(birthdate) ...`?

Comment: Because it would be shorter :D

Comment: You need to make all values as a part of one data structure. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/NarZnm)

Comment: that looks good, thanks!
Is it possible doing this using rest parameters instead of having to put the values into an array?

Comment: @t-MURO no, TS does not support it